# Case Expression for the Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query and I want to return the String instead of the Numbers, The Query has the value as `DegreeID`

```
select P.DegreeID, D.DegreeName, P.ProgramName
            from pagesite sp
                left join table2.Degrees D on P.DegreeID = D.DegreeID
```

I want to apply the case expression to the degreeID field like the swicth vase statement that if it is `1` name it like `masters` and if it is `2`, name it as `bachelors` and with default case of `others`

Comment: Have you Google it???

Answer (score 0):

```
    select case
            when D.DegreeID= 1
             then 'masters'
            when D.DegreeID= 2
             then 'bachelors'
            else'others'
           end as ImNotSureTheColumnNameYouWantHere
      from pagesite sp
 left join table2.Degrees D 
        on P.DegreeID = D.DegreeID
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to add `CASE` expression.  I'm pretty sure there are tons of example online.

```
SELECT (
    CASE P.DegreeID
        WHEN 1 THEN 'masters'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'bachelors'
        ELSE 'Others'
    END
    ) AS Degree
    , D.DegreeName, P.ProgramName
FROM pagesite sp
LEFT JOIN table2.Degrees D ON P.DegreeID = D.DegreeID
```